# Fix the layout of index with imakeidx: a new implementation

Tags: imakeidx, makeindex

With an ingenious very different implementation, in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/537677/41963) egreg helped me to obtain a custom style of index with `imakeidx` package. Although the layout is the one desired, it sometimes does not seem to work, especially with long names: as seen in the photo, "Author9" is not positioned correctly.

[image]

Also, I'd like to be able to define the amount of indentation of the subitems, which I would prefer to decrease:

[image]

Here is an MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.mst}
item_0 "\n\n \\item "
item_1 " \\firstlevel "
item_2 " \\secondlevel "
item_01 " \\firstlevel "
item_x1 " \\firstlevel "
item_12 " \\secondlevel "
item_x2 " \\secondlevel "
delim_0 ":~"
delim_1 ":~"
delim_2 ":~"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{article}

\usepackage[top=49.5mm,bottom=52.5mm,inner=39mm,outer=39mm, headheight=4mm, headsep=6mm, marginparwidth=14mm, marginparsep=2mm, nofoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon}}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_ale_index_item_seq
\seq_new:N \l_ale_index_subitem_seq
\tl_new:N \l_ale_index_author_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ale_index_work_tl
\dim_new:N \l_ale_index_indent_dim

\cs_set_protected:cpn { @idxitem } #1 \par
 {
  \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \firstlevel }
   {
    \tl_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { \secondlevel }
     {
      \ale_index_secondlevel:n { #1 }
     }
     {
      \ale_index_firstlevel:n { #1 }
     }
   }
   {
    \ale_index_nolevel:n { #1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ale_index_nolevel:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l_ale_index_item_seq \c_colon_str { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ale_index_item_seq \l_ale_index_author_tl
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \l_ale_index_author_tl, }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_ale_index_indent_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \par\hangindent\l_ale_index_indent_dim
  \l_ale_index_author_tl, \seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_item_seq { }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ale_index_secondlevel:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ale_index_item_seq { \firstlevel } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ale_index_item_seq \l_ale_index_author_tl
  \l_ale_index_author_tl\par\nobreak
  \seq_map_function:NN \l_ale_index_item_seq \ale_index_subitem:n
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ale_index_subitem:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ale_index_subitem_seq { \secondlevel } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ale_index_subitem_seq \l_ale_index_work_tl
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \qquad \l_ale_index_work_tl,~ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_ale_index_indent_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \par\hangindent\l_ale_index_indent_dim      % edited with intended indentation: \par\hangindent=2em
  \qquad\l_ale_index_work_tl,~\seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_subitem_seq { ~---~ }     % edited with intended indentation: \quad\l_ale_index_work_tl,~\seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_subitem_seq { ~---~ }
 } 

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ale_index_firstlevel:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ale_index_item_seq { \firstlevel } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ale_index_item_seq \l_ale_index_author_tl
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \l_ale_index_author_tl,~ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_ale_index_indent_dim { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \par\hangindent\l_ale_index_indent_dim   % edited with intended indentation:  \par\hangindent=1em
  \l_ale_index_author_tl,~\seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_item_seq { ~---~ }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeindex[name=1]
\makeindex[name=2]
\makeindex[name=3]
\makeindex[name=4,options=-s \jobname.mst]

\newcommand*{\cose}[1]{\index[1]{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand*{\parole}[1]{\index[2]{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand*{\autori}[1]{\index[4]{#1}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

text 

\autori{Author!Work1!1,15} 
\autori{Author!Work1!9,32}
\autori{Author!Work2!2,24} 
\autori{Author!Work2!5,11}
\autori{Author!Work2!2,25} 
\autori{Author!Work2!5,12}
\autori{Author!Work1!11,42}

\autori{Author2!4,34}
\autori{Author3!6,12} 
\autori{Author3!9,4}
\autori{Author4!9,4}
\autori{Author4!9,5}
\autori{Author4!2,6}
\autori{Author5!2,34}
\autori{Author6!2,4}
\autori{Author7!2,4}
\autori{Author8!2,12} 
\autori{Author 123456!2,12} 
\autori{Author 123456!2,13} 
\autori{Author 123456!2,14} 
\autori{Author 123456!2,15} 

\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,45} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,46} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,47} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,48} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,49} 
\autori{Author9 (ed. Author10)!Op. XYZ!2,50} 

\printindex[4]

\end{document}
```

EDIT 1: I managed to obtain the desired indentation writing `\par\hangindent=2em` and `\par\hangindent=1em` instead of `\par\hangindent\l_ale_index_indent_dim` in sections `\ale_index_subitem:n #1` and `\ale_index_firstlevel:n #1` respectively and `\quad\l_ale_index_work_tl,~\seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_subitem_seq { ~---~ }` instead of `\qquad\l_ale_index_work_tl,~\seq_use:Nn \l_ale_index_subitem_seq` { ~---~ } in section `\ale_index_subitem:n #1` (see the MWE).

[image]

EDIT 2: The solution proposed by Andrew Swann worked for me. 
I would like to ask if it is possible to get justified text in the index, because it is currently left aligned, as the following image shows:

[image]

EDIT 3: Loading the package idxlayout I obtained a justified, but now the distance between the reference and the page number is too big: How can I do in order to set a fixed distance between reference and page number?

[image]

Comment: Can't help with the tun-together items, but regarding the indentations, these are defined in `article.cls`.  Look for `\newcommand\@idxitem`, `\subitem` and `\subsubitem`.  Redefining those dimensions should be relatively easy to do in your preamble.

Comment: Adding `\par` to the end of `ale_index_nolevel:n`, `ale_index_secondlevel:n` and `ale_index_firstlevel:n` solves the run-in problem in your example and in other situations.  I have no idea if this in the spirit of the original code.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thanks, this solved the problem! Is it possible to stretch horizontally the text in order that each line fill all the paragraph?

Comment: @ALE Glad that helps.  For the stretching I am not really clear what you are asking for.  May be you could add some more explanation to the end of your question.

Comment: @AndrewSwann thank you, I inserted an image to explain what I mean.

Comment: Indexes are usually set ragged right.  If you instead want it set justified, it should be sufficient to patch the `\printindex` definition to remove that instruction.  However, all spaces will then expand at the same rate, making the association between reference and page number less clear.  It would be better to allow more stretch to just the spaces around the dash (the real "separator").

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, I loaded package idxlayout and now the text is justified, but  it gives the effect that you said (see image above). How can I do in order to set a fixed distance between reference and page number? Currently the "separator" is \,---~, but I can change it.

Comment: The space between reference and page number is generated by the writing out of the index terms, so changing that would not only be a pain, but would likely compromise the sort.  What you want to do instead is make the space after the dash more stretchable than any other space.  I would try `\hspace{.3em plus 5em}`, the `.3em` being close to the width of an ordinary interword space.  Stretch of `5em` should be enough to overpower the default stretchiness, but if it isn't, you can easily increase that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you very much. \,--\hspace{.3em plus 5em} could be well. However, I'm not entirely satisfied with the result and I think I'll use ;\hspace{.3em plus 5em} as a separator

Comment: Good accommodation (in my opinion); I think that will be much clearer for somebody looking up something in the index.  (But that's always subjective, and the author is generally right unless the result defies a publisher's stated specs.)

Comment: Is it possible to break an entry between two lines (the reference in a line and page number in another)? I see that it never happens, causing big white spaces