# Remove space after \else inside command definition

Tags: spacing, indexing, ifthenelse

I'm defining this command for my index: `\newcommand*{command}{\iffirstsubsubitem\unskip\firstsubsubitemfalse\ \else; \fi}` and I'm wondering if there is a way to eliminate the white space it prints just before the semicolon.

I tried with `\newcommand*{command}{\iffirstsubsubitem\unskip\firstsubsubitemfalse\ \else\kern{-1ex}; \fi}`, but the result isn't good.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright]{article}

\usepackage[top=49.5mm,bottom=52.5mm,inner=39mm,outer=39mm, headheight=4mm, headsep=6mm, marginparwidth=14mm, marginparsep=2mm, nofoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{latin}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeindex[name=1,title=,options=-s Intero.ist]
\makeindex[name=2,title=,options=-s Intero.ist]
\makeindex[name=3,title=,options=-s Intero.ist]
\makeindex[name=4,title=,options=-s Intero.ist]
\usepackage[itemlayout=singlepar,font=footnotesize]{idxlayout}

\usepackage{xpatch}


\makeatletter
\def\@idxitem{\par\addvspace{10\p@ \@plus 5\p@ \@minus 3\p@}\hangindent 40\p@}
\def\subitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{20\p@}}
\def\subsubitem{\par\hangindent 40\p@ \hspace*{30\p@}}
\def\indexspace{}
\patchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\indexname\vspace{12pt}}{}{}
\makeatother


\makeatletter
\newif\iffirstsubitem
\newif\iffirstsubsubitem
\renewcommand{\indexsubsdelim}{ }
\newcommand*{\indexsubsdelimb}{\iffirstsubsubitem\unskip\firstsubsubitemfalse\ \else; \fi}
\renewcommand{\subitem}{\iffirstsubitem\unskip\firstsubitemfalse, \else; \fi\firstsubsubitemtrue}%
\renewcommand{\subsubitem}{\indexsubsdelimb}%
\renewcommand{\@idxitem}{\par\setlength{\hangindent}{\ila@hangindent}\firstsubitemtrue}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\cose}[1]{\index[1]{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand*{\parole}[1]{\index[2]{#1}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand*{\autori}[1]{\index[4]{#1}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}


text

\autori{Author!Work1!1,15} 
\autori{Author!Work1!9,31}
\autori{Author!Work2!2,24} 
\autori{Author!Work2!5,11}
\autori{Author!Work2!2,25} 

\autori{Author2!4,34}
\autori{Author3!6,12} 
\autori{Author3!9,4}
\
\printindex[4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317), otherwise it will be difficult to help you. There is no explicit space before the semicolon here. Maybe you are using `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, which might explain some things, but I can't find my good crystal ball, so...

Comment: Sorry, I added an MWE

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't appear to be minimal.

Comment: Without these information you can't see the result printed in the index I think

Comment: It is possible that your problem is related to the index. Unfortunately, I'm not competent in this area, especially with `imakeidx` which I have never used. What I can say with certainty is that a space before the `;` here isn't caused by the `\iffirstsubitem ... \else ...  \fi` construct. Your code appears to define several macros twice (e.g., `\subitem`, `\subsubitem`). Why?

Comment: It modifies the layout of the index, see this question and the answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477447/41963

Comment: The answer there doesn't duplicate the definitions, AFAICS. Several of your `\def`s (at least 3) are completely useless due to the subsequent `\renewcommand`s.

Comment: Without testing.  This may not work, but is worth trying.  Move the `\unskip` before the `\iffirstsubitem`.  That `\if...` may insert bits that render the `\unskip` inoperative, and in any case, in its present position it doesn't apply to the `\else` condition, which is where the semicolon is inserted..

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an attempt to separate your index entry references by semicolons you have defined the following:

```
\newcommand*{command}{\iffirstsubsubitem\unskip\firstsubsubitemfalse\ \else; \fi}
```

Let's take a careful look at this.

Presumably the entries, after sorting, have a space after the page number.  You certainly don't want a space after a page number before the semicolon.  So you have specified `\unskip`, which is headed in the right direction.  However,  you insert the `\unskip` after testing for the first reference ... and then you explicitly insert a space *after* the reference ("first subsubitem").

But the `\iffirstsubsubitem` undoubtedly does some things that effectively separate what precedes that `\if...` from the `\unskip`, so that `\unskip` may have no effect (not tested, so I'm not sure).  However, whether or not the `\unskip` works there, you haven't done anything to remove the space that you wanted to obliterate before the semicolon.  You could add another `\unskip` after the `\else` and before the semicolon, but there's a better way.

Simply move the `\unskip` to the beginning of the definition, before the `\if...`, giving this:

```
\newcommand*{command}{\unskip\iffirstsubsubitem\firstsubsubitemfalse\ \else; \fi}
```